# Geometry textbook question

Tags: geometry, self-learning

I have just started the textbook Geometry: its elements and structure by Alfred Posamentier.

The first set of questions refers to the following diagram:

[image]

The very first question is "What is the intersection of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$?" If an intersection is defined as the set of all elements that are common to two sets. Then I think the answer should be an empty set since $\overline{AB}$ contains no elements in common with $\overline{CD}$. However, the solutions manual lists the answer as $\overline{CB}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the definition of "line" used? Usually line means all points (not just those between the points a,b used to define the line). Otherwise "line segment" is used if one only wants a,b and points between.

Comment: Actually, the textbook never says line it instead refers to a diagram. It is probably a line segment. The page I am referring to can be found on page 3 if you preview the textbook on amazon. http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Its-Elements-Structure-Mathematics/dp/0486492672. I understand that asking people to look at the preview may be a little much. I suppose I don't know how to explain it any better though.

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the preview, when the author writes $\overline{AB}$, they refer to the line segment (i.e. only points between $A$ and $B$ are considered). When the words "line $AB$" is used, they refer to the entire line extended to infinity. That said, I do agree with your answer of the empty set. It is most likely that there is a typo either in the question or the solutions

Comment: It actually looks like the solution to problem 2, are you sure you didn't look at the wrong answer?

Comment: The answer to problem 2 is CD. I just looked at the solutions manual. I am sure I have the right answer. Solutions manual can be found on the publisher's website here...http://www.doverpublications.com/solutions/492672.pdf. Warning it is a large file (18 mb).

Comment: Also, I don't think it would be the correct answer to problem 2. The union of CB and BD should be BD based on the diagram, right?

Comment: Perhaps there is a mismatch between editions. Could it be that an older edition of the book had slightly different questions, and the answers refer to these?

Comment: Yes, I think either that or a more substantial error across conditions. I e-mailed the editors at Dover with my concerns. They sent me a stock e-mail in reply. I have sent another e-mail, hopefully they will get back with a decent response soon. But, I am not hopeful.

Comment: @user183974 I wanted to ask the very same question, annoying typo to say the least. The very first problem and a wrong solution is provided.